# How do you pen test a REST API?

Tags: penetration-test, rest, api

We have a server that is running a REST API on port 443. I'd like to make sure it's secure by doing various pen tests on it. I'm used to doing offensive testing on a webpage where I can see code, and URLs, and find forms to test. But I'm completely blind when testing an API. I don't even know what are valid URLs to test against.
Is there any good documentation on how to do this, perhaps using Kali Linux?

Comment: Astra is one which I came across: > Astra can be used by security engineers or developers as an integral
> part of their process, so they can detect and patch vulnerabilities
> early during development cycle. Astra can automatically detect and
> test login & logout (Authentication API), so it's easy for anyone to
> integrate this into CICD pipeline. Astra can take API collection as an
> input so this can also be used for testing apis in standalone mode. https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/Astra

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[REST Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) and [API Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_API_Security_Project) are excellent topics of research.

This question and the answers provide good starting points to find great tools and techniques to test these interfaces -- [API Security Testing Methodologies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51010/api-security-testing-methodologies)

If I were you, I'd avoid testing a REST interface or an API's security remotely, or via a black-box technique such as dynamic app security testing. What you want is to analyze the design decisions (this [blog post](https://medium.com/@schneidenbach/restful-api-best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-7a83ba3763b5) is a great reference with .NET code examples and component recommendations) and/or perform a secure code review. One tool that I commonly use to perform secure code reviews is [Find Security Bugs](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io). For analyzing components, there is [OWASP Dependency Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) (with multiple language support), [bundler-audit](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) for Ruby, [Retire.js](http://retirejs.github.io/retire.js/) (or [Snyk.io](http://snyk.io)) for JavaScript, and OWASP [SafeNuGet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_SafeNuGet) for .NET projects.

Comment: https://github.com/openstack/syntribos

Comment: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs

Comment: https://bbva.github.io/apicheck/